# Help identifying this: fuse or switch?

Tags: electrical, battery, switches

I just got an '86 Honey RV that's got a 454 in it and am trying to decipher all of the wiring. There's a lot of junk in the front of the RV, some of which needs to be replaced and some of which can probably be removed.

Here is something that was wrapped in tape and comes off one of the two batteries in the front bay. The two batteries are separated by isolators but can be bridged together in parallel using an "emergency start" button next to the steering wheel for an extra boost of power.

It looks to me like this is maybe a thermal switch or fuse? You can see a contactor on the bottom right of the picture. Whoever did this was clearly making it so the contactors were always connected. I can't find any good comparison pictures using google images, searching for "thermal switch" so maybe that's not what it is. Does anyone have any idea? I'd like to know if I should find a replacement for whatever this is for or of I can simply switch it out for a single wire.

[image: electrical picture]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Where *exactly* do these go to (each end)? I think if you trace it back to origin you're going to be able to answer the question a lot easier.

Comment: It's in between the positive terminal of one battery and the isolator (the isolator that looks like it goes into the house part of the RV).

Comment: It would help if you draw a simple circuit diagram of how the components are connected including the batteries, contactors, fuses and switches etc. Is there any other wires attached to it, have you measured if theres any resistance? It could be as simple as a mounting, a shunt resistor (for measuring current) or a fuse

Comment: It may be really ugly, but could you check it to see if it may be a diode? I've not seen them look like that, but wondering if it might be a high amperage type (old school). If it will pass juice both ways, then the only thing I would think it would be is a fusible link or just a post connector (either of which would be made for high amperage).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ahh good idea! I will check if it's a diode when I get home. That might make more sense than a fuse. It is very easy to separate the contacts using a little bit of force which is what made me think it might be a thermal something or other. It also seems like there may have once been a case around it that broke apart, hence someone taping it together. It's tough to sketch out a whole diagram since a lot of the wires go through the firewall to who-knows-where. At some point I'll try to make a whole diagram but I was wondering if anyone knew what this was off the top of their head.

Comment: I may just be a junction block.

Comment: @Moab - That's what I actually meant to say and not a "post connector" ... brain fart.

Comment: It could also be a thermal (amp) limiter. A self resetting fuse.

Comment: Okay so yeah, I'm 95% sure it's an automotive type auto-resetting thermal circuit breaker, which I think is what you meant by "thermal amp limiter" @Moab. I will post an answer with a picture of a new one. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @tbox OK, what is the stud size on the fuse? 1/4 inch? What is the wire size of the wires connected to it, 12 or 10 gauge?

Comment: @Moab - Ah, I see it now. The bottom portion is the heated part with the contact point to the right side of the picture. Good call :o) If this was all taped up, though, how did it work? (I'm thinking it wasn't.)

Comment: Yeah it was definitely not working. My guess is when the casing fell off someone was like "hey I better tape this up!" 

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Moab and my neighborhood auto parts store, I found what I was looking for. It looks to be a crusty old automotive thermal circuit breaker without its case.

Here is what a newer one looks like with the case on:

[image: thermal circuit breaker]

Comment: Hard part is determining what amperage it is.

Comment: Indeed. Any suggestions? Or should I go off the wire Guage that it's supplying?